# Android GCM Manifest and application setup and unit testing

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Though I've followed the tutorial on Android Dev Site (I'm using the newer GCM API) I want to be sure that I've gotten everything right with regards to the GCM Setup, so I'll break it up into the following sections:

**Manifest File:**

1) My Application package name is: package="com.abc.xyz.demo"

```
<permission android:name="com.abc.xyz.demo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"   android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.abc.xyz.demo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

My Broadcast Receiever & Intent Service are in the Manifest as follows:

```
 <receiver
            android:name="com.abc.xyz.demo.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.abc.xyz.demo" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.abc.xyz.demo.gcm.GCMIntentService" />
```

The com.abc.xyz.demo.gcm package has the GCMBroadcastReceiver & the GCMIntentService. I'm using the Broadcast Receiver only for now (since the tutorial mentions that IntentService is optional) as follows:

```
public class GCMBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    Context ctx;

    public TWGCMBroadcastReceiver() 
    {
        Log.i("GCMAudit", "Receiver Instaniated!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
        ctx = context;

        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (messageType != null && messageType.length() > 0)
        {
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) 
                sendNotification("Send error: " + intent.getExtras().toString());
            else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) 
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +intent.getExtras().toString());
            else 
                sendNotification("Received: " + intent.getExtras().toString());

            setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        }
        else
        {
            setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
        }
    }

        // Put the GCM message into a notification and post it.
private void sendNotification(String msg) 
{
    mNM = (NotificationManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent cI = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, new Intent(ctx, Main.class), 0);
    ...
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Please note that I can register successfully, and send out the regId to our Application server (I don't have direct access to the server right now)

Some general queries here:

1) Does our Web Application server or GCM need to know my Package Name? If so, do I need to send it out explicitly? Currently I'm only sending out the sender Id from the Google Project.

2) If Package name is an issue, how do I match the Android Application's package name with the one (if any) at the Server?

3) Is the above broadcast receiver implementation sufficient for testing purposes? Or no messages will ever appear unless I write out a service as well? (I don't expect so)

4) How do I unit test the broadcast receiver? Since I cannot manipulate the server at the moment (only have a web UI to send out messages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCM gets the package name implicitly when you register.  As for your server getting the package name, that would be required if your server sends GCM messages to more than one app. In that case when you send a registration id to your server you'll want to send additional data specifing the app that this registration id belongs to.

The broadcast receiver is enough.  You don't need the intent service.

I'm not sure what you mean in the last question.  Do you have a way to send messages to your app or don't you? You need to send messages in order to test the broadcast receiver.

Comment: That pretty much answers the questions I had, from what I understand, as long as the Broadcast receiver & service names are fully qualified, everything should work as expected. Lint would throw up errors if either of the receiver or service were uninstantiable. Correct?



For the last question, yes I do have one, but don't have access to it yet, I guess writing a unit test would be the way till I can get hold of the server, i.e. mimic messages to the broadcast receiver somehow?

Comment: Everything was sorted out, I didn't need to change anything at client side. For anyone interested, I used this popular gcm library https://github.com/ToothlessGear/node-gcm 

As a final adjustment, I just updated the SENDER_ID (we were receiving MismatchSenderID) which has the notifications running for us now.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple.

Your app talks to `GCM server` and gets the `registration ID`. The register method needs context to internally fetch the package name. You **NEED NOT** send it anywhere explicitly.

Once you get the Registration ID you send it to your app server.

Your app server then uses the same `RegId` to send you any push message. But the app server does not communicate to your mobile directly. It sends the message to GCM server with the registration id and the `API_KEY`.

The GCM server already knows your phone through the unique reg id. So GCM server sends the push message it further to your mobile. In the entire process only the GCM SERVER is aware of you and your device and **NO ONE** else. So the entire process can happen only via GCM Server.

Also one important thing to understand is that the package name that was used while getting the registration id is sent back with every push message. In the broadcast receiver the package name can be obtained in the following way:

```
 String category = intent.getPackage();
```

Hope this helps.